# implementing stripe php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i am new to Stripe and Oauth. i am developing a  crowdfunding platform in php (similar to kickstarter.com) .

These are my questions regarding [stripe connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect):

1. From what i understand about stripe connect, we can send the money contributed to a 
   campaign directly to the campaign creator's account rather than sending all the money to a main account
   and then the main account holder having to transfer the money to individual account(campaign creator). 
   is this correct?
2. When the campain creator connects to stripe, it will return an access token and a publishable key(https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started).
   Should i store these values in my db so that when the contributor clicks on contribute button for 
   a particular campaign, i can get the tokens associated with the campaign creator and then make the api calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you are right. All the money contributed to a campaign can go  straight to the campaign's creator stripe account(to be transfer to the bank account they set up).
2. Yes, you need to store both the access token and a publishable key in your DB. You are required to send user's access_token and publishable_key while doing the  Stripe API calls for making payments.

Comment: thanks.one more thing..i dont have a seperate admin backend for the campaign creator. So is it okay if i put the stripe connect button in the settings page inside the campaign creators profile?

Comment: Yes, you can put the stripe connect button inside campaign creators profile and once campaign creator connected to stripe and you got  access token and a publishable key into your DB, you can hide that stripe connect button for that creator.